# Passing Emissions Test: Can't figure out how to fix code P0705 on a 1997 Nissan D21 / Hardbody / Pickup

Tags: transmission, nissan, emissions

So hello. I have had a lot of luck with my other vehicles on forums and a recently became the (hopefully-soon-to-be)-proud owner of a 1997 Nissan D21/Hardbody/Pickup XE. It has 156k miles on it and is completely stock. 2.4l 5spd 4WD. It runs like a dream, gets great gas mileage, little rust on frame, none on body and bed. All in all, a great truck.

I wanted this specific model truck after reading extensive reviews on their reliability (some say "to a fault"!) and longevity and the fact it is such a badass utilitarian vehicle. I went to go see about 12 before I found the one I currently own. Now, because NH is notorious for it's salt in the winter and D21s are notorious for their frame rust, I had to go to Maine to get it. Maine, where I find out they will slap a sticker on a watermelon. Once I get to NH, I realized, for the first time, just how nasty computerized emissions tests can be.

So far, I have replaced 2 air sensors, a catalytic converter, a speed sensor, fixed an EVAP system leak. Now I am at the one I am stuck on. Where the first list of repairs took about 2 weeks, this one has taken about two months and is still not fixed no matter what we do. Now I am stuck at my mechanic's (unless I pay $450 to have it towed to the closest Nissan dealer) unless I am trying to do the drive cycle and even that is technically illegal. If I do drive, cops around here have a boner for people flying the "illegal vehicle" flag and I will most certainly be arrested and the truck impounded (I already have a ticket AND I was pulled over 6 times while under a 60 day emissions sticker).

The code is P0705: Transmission Range Sensory Malfunction (PRNDL Input)

I replaced the neutral switch (which the dealer said is the range sensor) but lo and behold, the "service engine soon" light came on again after about 21 miles.

Weird things:

-Before the neutral switch was installed, I had to drive over 53 mph for more than a mile AFTER at least 17 miles since cleared codes before the check engine light flipped on. Otherwise, I could drive the car all day under 53 and it would never trip the light, but it would also never "be ready" according to the state's inspection computer.

-Before the NS, the car sucked at higher speeds. We're talking accelerating from 60 mph to 70 mph took over a minute with pedal to the metal.

-On the latest drive cycle test after I had the neutral switch installed, the car was running better than it ever had while I owned it. Better acceleration and lower RPMs at high speeds. The accelerator pedal was much more responsive, especially in 5th gear.

-After the neutral switch was installed, I could drive for as long as I wanted without tripping the check engine light (would still register not ready) until I stopped the engine, restarted it, then drove above 53 mph for more than a mile.

-Checked blown fuses, but all are OK.

Regardless, the tranny does not buck or anything. As I said, the truck runs like a dream.

I feel like my mechanic's are getting annoyed with the truck and their motivation has ceased. As much as I am going to change my mechanic as a result, I am committed to these one's to fix the truck unless I want to risk getting arrested.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially things I can do/check in the parking lot of my mechanic's shop.

Thanks for any assistance. I know I am new but please help! It's getting too cold to ride the motorcycle to work!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved, Filip? [Electronic Versions](http://www.nicoclub.com/FSM/hardbody/) of the Service Manuals are available online, and there are a couple of nice online communities specifically for the D21 Hardbody at [Nissan Forum](http://nissanforum.org/nissan-forum/forumdisplay.php?f=20) and [Infamous Nissan](http://www.infamousnissan.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=21).

Answer (score 2):

If the sensor was replaced and you still have problems, then it's either the sensor, the sensor's circuit, or the ECU. Since it's a new sensor, I would check the circuit. If the mechanic it is at cannot do this, then your best bet is to head to a Nissan dealer.

The current mechanic will likely need the factory service manual for this model to properly check the circuit, which some mechanics do carry depending on how specialized they are.